# How to disable paste /undo/Clipboard/ in InputEditText In Android (If u Long Press on Cursor its able to displaying paste /undo things )

Tags: java, android, kotlin

`                              android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:longClickable="false"
android:importantForAutofill="no"

```
 **** accountnumber.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
       Control pop of paste/undo/ Clipboard ? we need control paste should not happend and account number has ? textpassword thing                    `
```